# Video Call For IOS

Tags: ios, video, call

How to make video call from app.

Is there any sample or tutorial,

I'm struggling with this help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Video calling there is one open source library available. Which is known as [linphone](https://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html). Such a great library. I have also use this library in one of our project and it's working great.

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

I just develop an ios project do video calling by WebRTC and Firebase.

Including testing on simulator and run on real device.

https://github.com/congtung10t2/VideoCallWebRTCFirebase